# Facebook api get post of specific user

Tags: facebook-graph-api

Im trying to inquire an open and public group  by using the graph API

```
https://graph.facebook.com/396697410351933/feed?{TOKEN}
```

So far so good and i'm receiving a json with the latest posts

is there any way to get only specific user post by using the  from.id value

```
"from": {
            "id": "123456",
            "name": "XXXX"
         },
```

somthing like that

```
https://graph.facebook.com/396697410351933/feed?{TOKEN}&id=123456
```

thanks,

miki

Answer (score 1):

There's currently no way to filter this via the Graph API. If you have access to a Graph API v2.0 app, you could use FQL to filter as you desire. Be aware that FQL will be deprecated in August 2016.

See

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/stream/

Try `actor_id` as the ID of the person which posted the post, and `source_id` as the group id.

Sample query:

```
select actor_id, message, created_time from stream where source_id=396697410351933 and actor_id=10152352765098713
```